# Как правильно делать модальное окно, которое больше высоты экрана?

Tags: html, css

Имеется модальное окно:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.site {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: red;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 1000px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
  
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="content">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Оно больше высоты экрана, что делать в таком случаи, как сделать так что бы можно было скролить окно, либо какое-то другое решение.

`overflow: auto;` не помогает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```css
.modalDialog {
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  display: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<a href="#openModal">Открыть модальное окно</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Закрыть" class="close">x</a>
    <h2>Модальное окно</h2>
    <p>Прмер простого модального окна, которое может быть создано с использованием CSS3.</p>
    <p>Его можно использовать в широком диапазоне, начиная от вывода сообщений и заканчивая формой регистрации.</p>
    <p>Его можно использовать в широком диапазоне, начиная от вывода сообщений и заканчивая формой регистрации.</p>
    <p>Его можно использовать в широком диапазоне, начиная от вывода сообщений и заканчивая формой регистрации.</p>
    <p>Его можно использовать в широком диапазоне, начиная от вывода сообщений и заканчивая формой регистрации.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```